# Using Clojure vector to model a 7 card poker hand

Tags: clojure

I have a vector that represents a 7 card poker hand and I want to find the next hand using the following method:

- values are from 0 to 12 and are sorted (e.g. `[0 0 7 11 11 12 12]`)
- A valid vector has atmost 4 of one value
- The first valid vector is `[0 0 0 0 1 1 1]`
- If the values at `index` and `index + 1` are different then increment the value at `index` *and* set all the values from `0` to `index - 1` to zero
- Repeat the last step until the vector is valid

For example, `(next-hand [0 0 0 0 1 1 1])` would return `[0 0 0 1 1 1 1]` directly.  However, `(next-hand [0 0 0 1 1 1 1])` would loop through,

```
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1] (invalid)
[0 1 1 1 1 1 1] (invalid)
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1] (invalid)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 2] (invalid)
[0 0 0 0 0 1 2] (invalid)
```

and return this valid hand:

```
[0 0 0 0 1 1 2]
```

Here is the sudo code I have, but need to convert this to clojure.  Note how I'm adding a really large integer to the end of the hand to make the last comparison always true.  Thus, in the case of `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 99]` the first loop would end at `i=6` with `1 < 99 == true`.

```
let hand = [hand 99]
while hand is invalid
  for i in range(0,6)
    if hand[i] < hand[i+1]
      increment hand[i]
      break
  for j in range(0,i-1)
    hand[j] = 0
```

**Edit Friday, Mar 29, 2013:**
In order for the select solution to work with the poker hand model I added an `is-valid` function like so:

```
(defn is-valid [v]
  (let [distinct-ranks (partition-by identity v)
        count-distinct (map count distinct-ranks)
        max-count (apply max count-distinct)]
    (<= max-count 4)))
```

and updated to `(filter #(is-valid %)` in `next-hand`.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `core.logic`.

Comment: @AlexTaggart: Don't think so, doesn't sounds like relational/constrain problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
(defn next [v]
  (let [i (->> (map <  v (rest v))
               (map-indexed vector)
               (filter #(% 1))
               first)
        index (if i (i 0) 6)]
    (for [[i x] (map-indexed vector v)]
      (cond (= i index) (inc x)
            (< i index) 0
            :else x))))

(defn next-hand [v]
  (->> (iterate next (next v))
       (filter #(= 4 (apply + %)))
       first
       vec))

(next-hand [0 0 0 1 1 1 1])
```

Comment: This is so close.  The `next` function is perfect.  However, `next-hand` doesn't quit evaluate to a valid next hand.  I think, and I'll try to post it tomorrow, it needs a `valid-hand` function to stop.  Can you explain how the `iterate` works with the other parts.  What stop the iterate?

Comment: The `filter` in `next-hand` is used to find the valid hand. In this case valid hand is something where sum of vector is 4, may be you meant something else by valid hand. `iterate` will generate an infintie sequence of hands where next hand is based on prev hand.